# jinja2/flask change variable value

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to change the value of a variable inside a loop, this way I can do some stuff for the first iteration only, then do other stuff for all the next iterations.

```
{% set vars = {'foo': True} %}
{% for line in project[2].split('[newline]') %}
 {% if vars.foo %}
  its true!
 {% else %}
  its false!
 {% endif %}
{% vars.update({'foo': False}) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Output looks like 'its true! its true! its true! its true!', so Jinja definitely doesnt get the fact that the variable has been changed.

I've also tried to swap `{% vars.update({'foo': False}) %}` for `{% vars.foo == False %}` but it didn't worked.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

I fixed my problem!

No need to use a variable, Jinja2 has something that counts the number of iteration in a loop.

So I just changed my code like this:

```
  {% for line in project[2].split('[newline]') %}
    {% if loop.index == 1 %}
      its true!
    {% else %}
      its false!
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```